# How to find directories with 4-symbol unicode characters eg `<0328>`

Tags: bash, zsh, ls, unicode

While backing up my directories, the ones with names containing Polish characters like ę, ą, ż, ź, etc got "duplicated".

When I do `ls -al` I get response like:

```
drwxrwxr-x+ 310 root users     313 Oct  9 16:18  .
drwxrwxr-x+  13 root users      14 Dec  1  2019  ..
drwxrwxr-x+   2 root users      83 May 16  2021 '050805 - PKP Międzyzdroje'
drwxrwxr-x+   2 root users      83 Nov  8  2019 '050805 - PKP Międzyzdroje'
```

But then, when I try to do something with the directory (eg `ls`, or `mv`) zsh autocompletes the directories differently:

1. option with properly encoded "ę": `ls 050805\ -\ PKP\ Międzyzdroje/`
2. option with 4-symbol unicode character "<0328>": `ls 050805\ -\ PKP\ Mie<0328>dzyzdroje/`

**Question**: How can I find all directories containing these 4-symbol unicode characters so I can rename it to some ASCII name and then dedup them?

FWIW, my host is on Debian, but I might have caused the issue using macOS client via Samba.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have some files with that `ę` in its precomposed form (U+0119 LATIN SMALL LETTER E WITH OGONEK) and one with it in its decomposed form with `e` followed by U+0328 COMBINING OGONEK.

macOS is known to convert text to the decomposed form in filenames causing all sorts of problems.

To find filenames containing that U+0328 character, with `zsh`:

```
ls -ld -- **/*$'\u328'*(D)
```

Or to find those with any combining mark:

```
set -o rematchpcre
ls -ld -- **/*(De['[[ $REPLY:t =~ "\pM" ]]'])
```

Or defining a helper function:

```
hasMarks() {
  set -o localoptions -o rematchpcre
  [[ $REPLY:t =~ '\pM' ]]
}
ls -ld -- **/*(D+hasMarks)
```

To convert from decomposed to precomposed, in any POSIX-like shell and assuming file names don't end in newline characters:

```
precomposed=$(printf '%s\n' "$decomposed" | uconv -x nfc)
```

Or in `zsh` without having to make that assumption:

```
printf -rN - $decomposed | uconv -x nfc | IFS= read -rd '' precomposed
```

(`uconv` in the `icu-devtools` package on Debian).

So, to rename those, in `zsh`:

```
set -o rematchpcre -o pipefail
for file (**/*(NDode['[[ $REPLY:t =~ "\pM" ]]']))
  print -rN - $file:t | uconv -x nfc | IFS= read -rd '' new &&
    mv -Tvi -- $file $file:h/$new
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I slightly modified your script to rename it to `DEDUP___<original_name>` instead. That way I could diff and check it manually in next step.

`mv -Tvi -- $file $file:h/DEDUP___$new`